How to fix image comparison slider position on landscape mode in react native?
I am trying to the build the image comparison slider on react native like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-compare-slider. I almost build the component in portrait mode. But, when I tried to do the same in landscape mode means, the slider dragging is not working as expected.
Here's the code
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';
// import {CompareSlider} from 'react-native-compare-slider';

const ImageComparisonSlider = ({
  leftImage,
  rightImage,
  initialPosition = 0.5,
}) => {
  const [sliderPosition, setSliderPosition] = useState(
    new Animated.Value(initialPosition * Dimensions.get('window').width),
  );
  const [leftImageLoaded, setLeftImageLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [rightImageLoaded, setRightImageLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isDeviceRotated, setisDeviceRotated] = useState(false);

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
      const newPosition = Math.max(
        0,
        Math.min(gestureState.moveX, Dimensions.get('window').width),
      );

      sliderPosition.setValue(newPosition);
    },
  });

  const renderImage = (imageUri, onLoadEnd, style) => (
    <Image
      source={{uri: imageUri}}
      style={style}
      resizeMode="cover"
      onLoadEnd={onLoadEnd}
    />
  );

  const bothImagesLoaded = leftImageLoaded && rightImageLoaded;

  const onOrientationDidChange = orientation => {
    if (orientation == 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT' || orientation == 'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT') {
      setisDeviceRotated(true);
    } else {
      setisDeviceRotated(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(onOrientationDidChange);
    return () => Orientation.removeOrientationListener(onOrientationDidChange);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: isDeviceRotated ? '50%' : '100%',
        height: !isDeviceRotated ? '50%' : '100%', // Adjust as needed
        position: 'relative',
      }}>
      {!bothImagesLoaded && (
        <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
      )}
      {bothImagesLoaded && (
        <>
          {renderImage(rightImage, () => {}, styles.image)}
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.leftImageContainer,
              {
                width: sliderPosition,
              },
            ]}>
            {renderImage(leftImage, () => {}, styles.leftImage)}
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View
            style={[styles.sliderLine, {left: sliderPosition}]}
            {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <View style={styles.sliderHandle} />
          </Animated.View>
        </>
      )}
      <Image
        source={{uri: leftImage}}
        style={styles.hiddenImage}
        onLoad={() => setLeftImageLoaded(true)}
      />
      <Image
        source={{uri: rightImage}}
        style={styles.hiddenImage}
        onLoad={() => setRightImageLoaded(true)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  leftImageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  leftImage: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: '100%',
  },
  sliderLine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  sliderHandle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: -10,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    transform: [{translateY: -10}],
  },
  loaderContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  hiddenImage: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  },
});

export default ImageComparisonSlider;



Please check this as well: https://www.loom.com/share/4dc8d887fe1449268c8c944aa25f6dbd
It will be very helpful if I got the solution and Please let me know if there are any other packages out there to fix this issue
Thanks in advance!

You probably need to reset the window width when the screen changes orientation. It seems like you have the state update but the window width is initialized but never updated if you switch orientations.
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get("window").width);

const onOrientationDidChange = orientation => {
  if (orientation == 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT' || orientation == 'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT') {
    setisDeviceRotated(true);
  } else {
    setisDeviceRotated(false);
  }
  setWindowWidth(Dimensions.get("window").width);
};

You could also try using the useWindowDimensions hook like const width = useWindowDimensions().width;
